# How to handle 100000 rows in UItableview in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Which is the best way to implement -

1. Fetch the first 25 records and display when user click on more then again fetch from the server.
2. Fetch all the records from the server and store in DB and fetch 25 records from DB and display in table and repeat.
3. Or any other suggestions.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to display 100000 rows!?

Comment: The first approach is good if records are in thousand. and you can use the method of pull to refresh for table.

Comment: @Prashant Actually i have an Xml file which have offer list in lacs so i have to display.

Comment: It depends on how much time it takes to fetch all records at a time & store them in DB. If it takes less time then, you can get all records from DB & set dataSource for tableview. Table view will not have any performance or memory issues if you are reusing cells.

Comment: @Arun You can fetch first 25 from the server and cache them locally, next time user opens the app load them from the cache. I still don't why would any one want browse through 100K records!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching all records at the same time and then displaying in fractions is an approach but NOT a good one as loading for the first time will take a lot of time while fetching them from the web server.

You simply cannot ask user to wait for too long when it comes to making apps for iOS or any other mobile platform.

Also fetching 100000 items does not make sense because no one will want to go through all of them.

If the records are static, then you should consider adding them in DB and pre-loading with the app.

If the records are not static, for example, if its a website and more records are updated in it, then fetching and loading in small fractions is the right choice and when user demands more, you fetch and load more.

Comment: You are right @Jessice,Records are dynamic so fetching and loading in small fractions is the right choice.